# $(g\circ f)^{-1}=f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

When $f$ and $g$ are invertible functions we have 
$$(g\circ f)^{-1}=f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}$$

I think we have this in every Group $(A,*,u,')$

$(a*b)=c$

$(a*b)*b'=a=c*b'$

$c'*a=c'*(c*b')=b'$

$(c'*a)*a'=b'*a'$

> $$c'=(a*b)'=b'*a'$$

and in general we have

$(a_1*a_2*...*a_n)'=a_n'*...*a_2'*a_1'$

1)What is the specific name of this theorem?

2)There is something wrong with my derivation?

**EDIT**
Can we see this as a property of a function $f:A\rightarrow A$ on a structure $(A,\circ)$:

$f(x\circ y)=f(y)\circ f(x)$

?

Comment: This is the inverse property in group theory.

Comment: You could say $a\mapsto a'$ is an antiisomorphism.

Comment: @xavierm02 thanks that what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) There isn't one as far as I know! It's just a well known fact. See e.g. http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Matrix_Product

2) Your derivation is a little roundabout, but perfectly correct. I'd just write $ab\cdots c c'\cdots b'a' = \iota$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a theorem, just a trivial fact that's easily obtained from the definition of an inverse and associativity.

$$(f \circ g) \circ (g^{-1} \circ f^{-1}) = f \circ (g \circ g^{-1}) \circ f^{-1} = f \circ f^{-1} = 1$$

Comment: yea, that derivation is very easier. now seems moore trivial.