# Show that $(g \circ f)^{-1} = f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $f: A \to B$ and $g: B \to C$ be invertible mappings; that is, mappings such that $f^{-1}$ and $g^{-1}$ exist. Show that $(g \circ f)^{-1} = f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}$.

I tried using the facts that $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$ and $g^{-1}(g(x)) = x$ but that didn't seem to help and got me trivial statements.

Comment: apply (g o f)(x) from right on both sides to your claim, and then use associativity on the right side and the definition of inverse on the left side

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/367486/9464

Answer (score 4):

You have to show that $f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}$ is the inverse of $g\circ f$. Hence you have to show that $$f^{-1}\circ g^{-1} \circ g\circ f = id_A$$ and $$g\circ f \circ f^{-1}\circ g^{-1} = id_C.$$ Can you finish ?

Comment: So a function is invertible if it has both a pre and post inverse?

Comment: Yes, $g$ is the inverse of $f$ iff $g\circ f = id$ and $f\circ g = id$.